# How to filter for a combination of list arguments and multiple character strings in dplyr

Tags: r, functional-programming

Given a dataframe:

```
v1_attr1 <- c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1) %>% as.integer ()
v1_attr2 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1) %>% as.integer ()
v2_attr1 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0)  %>% as.integer ()
v2_attr2 <- c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0)  %>% as.integer ()

df <- data.frame (v1_attr1, v1_attr2, v2_attr1, v2_attr2)
```

How can I set a filter for the `attr` of each `v[[x]]`?

I tried the following code to get the number of rows in each `data.frame` filtered by `attr`.

```
library(dplyr)

# create list for vs
list_vs <- list ("v1", "v2")

# set multiple attr filter for each v[[x]] to get the respective number of rows in each filtered data.frame (presented in a list)
filtered <- lapply (list_vs, function (x){
  df %>% filter (noquote(paste0(list_vs[[x]], "_attr1")) == 1 | noquote(paste0(list_vs[[x]], "_attr2")) == 1) %>%
  nrow ()
})
```

Although this code doesn't return an error, the result for `filtered[[x]]` is always 0. How do I need to set the filter arguments correctly to get the desired number of rows in each `data.frame`? I used `noquote` because otherwise filtering arguments would be pasted in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
map(.x = list_vs,
    ~ df %>%
     filter_at(vars(starts_with(.x)), any_vars(. == 1)))

[[1]]
  v1_attr1 v1_attr2 v2_attr1 v2_attr2
1        1        0        0        0
2        0        1        0        0
3        1        1        0        0
4        0        1        1        1
5        0        1        1        1
6        0        1        1        1
7        1        1        0        0
8        1        1        0        0

[[2]]
  v1_attr1 v1_attr2 v2_attr1 v2_attr2
1        0        0        1        0
2        0        0        0        1
3        0        1        1        1
4        0        1        1        1
5        0        1        1        1
```

Comment: That's a nice and concise solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An option is to convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` by automatically picking up the patterns from the column names, and then do a `group_by`, `filter_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_sep = "_", 
          names_to = c('group', '.value' )) %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   filter_at(vars(-group_cols()), any_vars(. == 1))
```